# Can I use my GTA V Social Club account on two different consoles?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

I have my GTA V copy for PS3, but I have an Xbox 360 as well.  If someone lends me the game for Xbox, can I install it and use my PS3 Social Club account for online mode in the Xbox 360?

Comment: You should be able to because it's a third party service.

Comment: Just log into your Social Club account and link your Playstation Network and Xbox Live accounts to your account (Social Club).

Comment: You definitely can use the same profile on the same game for different platforms, but I highly doubt you can just complete 50% of the game on one platform and the other 50% on the other and have 100% completion. Your GTA 5 progress will likely be divided into PS3 progress and Xbox 360 progress.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Social Club account is device independent, as long as each device uses the same login details for the account you play the game with.

It's obviously just the Social Club that is shared though, not achievements and game progress.